# Gson is not serializing a predefined field

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

The field **__type** is not serialized in the JSON request. While everything was ok with the java version. It is the same even if I put it in the constructor with a default value or in the init block. I need this field to be always the string "File" but it is null obviously.

```
@Parcelize
data class File(var url: String?,
                var name: String?) : Parcelable {
    private var __type = "File"
}
```

Same with the following code

```
@Parcelize
data class File(
        @SerializedName("url") var url: String?,
        @SerializedName("name") var name: String?,
        @SerializedName("__type") var type: String = "File") : Parcelable
```

**The JSON**

```
{  
    "name":"sample_name.jpg",
    "url":"https://images.com/1123.jpg"
}
```

Comment: why don't you put __type in the constructor as well ?

Comment: @Ayusch Please, read again what I've written.

Comment: What rule am I breaking in order to get downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

You can find in the documentation that when using `@Parcelize` annotation, only primary constructor parameters will be serialized:

```
Instructs the Kotlin compiler to generate `writeToParcel()`, `describeContents()`
[android.os.Parcelable] methods, as well as a `CREATOR` factory class automatically.

The annotation is applicable only to classes that implements
[android.os.Parcelable] (directly or indirectly).
Note that only the primary constructor properties will be serialized.
```

Comment: Same with the field in the constructor.

Comment: Maybe there is something with this `@SerializedName`? Try with name of the field the same as in the json.

Comment: For some reason the field is null despite the default value

Comment: I think there might be a problem with the `@Parcelize` annotation itself and the 
compiler not taking account of default field value, since it is an experimental feature.

Comment: Switched back to java. Problem gone.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
class File{
    @SerializedName("name")
    public var name: String? = null
    @SerializedName("url")
    public var url: String? = null
}
```

Comment: How does this help serializing the field __type?